# Can't bitblt CBitmap to dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

Thanks for reading this.

I need to draw CBitmap instance which created by bitmap info header and byte array. Because I want them to be able to manipulate it real time in the future. Can't use LoadImage or such APIs that access my hard drive. Memory operations only.

Here's what I've tried.

```
void CBMPLoaderDlg::drawBitmapFromPath(CString path)
{
    CFile file;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
    BYTE* bits = NULL;

    CBitmap bm;
    CDC *clientDC;
    CDC memDC;

    try
    {
        if(! file.Open(path, CFile::modeRead))
            throw "File not found";

        if(file.Read(&bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)) < sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER))
            throw "Not bmp file";
        if(file.Read(&bih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)) < sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER))
            throw "Not bmp file";
        bits = new BYTE[bih.biSizeImage];
        if(file.Read(bits, bih.biSizeImage) < bih.biSizeImage)
            throw "Not bmp file";

        if(! bm.CreateBitmap(bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, bih.biPlanes, bih.biBitCount, bits))
            throw "Could not create bitmap";
        clientDC = this->GetDC();
        memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(clientDC);
        memDC.SelectObject(bm);

        clientDC->BitBlt(0, 0, bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    }
    catch(char *e)
    {
        TRACE("%s\n", e);
    }
}
```

The headers and byte array loads fine. And CBitmap creates fine too. Problem is, Bitblt returns TRUE but no changes on the dialog. Yes, Bitblt just be performed when OnPain() is called. I've tried that and result doesn't vary. I made this way to post this thread.

Am I getting it wrong? Please a little help would be great.

Comment: OK so just to be clear, you're doing the above in the OnPaint of a dialog, you're sure that function is actually called (in the debugger) yet when you bitblt to the paintDC instead of the clientdc, it still doesn't work? And the HBITMAP of your bm (CBitmap) is a valid resource handle?

Comment: Also, when you call some other functions on your clientDC (TextOut, MoveTo/LineTo, whatever) do they show up? When doing something like this, it's best to first draw something simple so you're sure the drawing works OK, and then move on to what you're actually trying to draw (bitmaps are always complex and finicky to get right).

Comment: If I change `if(! bm.CreateBitmap(...` to `if (!bm.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1))` (i.e. from a resource), it works fine, although the loaded data appears to be sensible. I don't know what the difference is.

Comment: Yes, It paints well. Text, Fill methods... but not that bitmap. And how do i now if the handle is valid??

Comment: [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229.aspx): *"`biSizeImage`: Specifies the size, in bytes, of the image. This can be set to 0 for uncompressed RGB bitmaps."* Make sure to handle that scenario, by calculating the image size from the image dimensions.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not 0 last time I checked.

Comment: Solved. I used CreateDIBitmap. But why the hell that code of mine doesn't work??

Comment: Your code does not create a device-independent bitmap. It creates a bitmap object that reflects the on-disk image. This is apparently not compatible with your destination DC (`clientDC`).

Comment: So, CBitmap is just a puppet for the bitmap file in disk huh?